# How to make a div fill the current page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to create a document using HTML which when it's printed, adds a 'cover page' with a border. I have a div that's only visible with '@media print', but I can't figure out how to get that div to fill the page. Setting a height of 100% with position: absolute fills the entire document, not just that one page.

Is there a way of restricting the size of the div to just the current page? When I tried position: fixed, it did put it in the right place, but on every page. In essence, I need to find a way to set height to the viewport height, but maintain position: absolute.

For this purpose, I'm restricted to a solution compatible with IE8 only.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between page and document as you're using them here?

Comment: Simply put, a document has multiple pages, separated using `div.section { page-break-before: always; }`.

Comment: So, you're wanting multiple pages worth of content loaded onto the page at the same time, but only one view-able at a time? I'm assuming your issue is you're covering some sort of UI features? Any jsfiddle and/or image to show what you're expecting to have happen?

Comment: No, a document has multiple pages, using paged media (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html). I want a div filling the first page, only the first page, and not the whole document.

Answer (score 1):

Give your html and body a height of 100% then the cover a height of 100% to get a cover height based on the viewport. Give the cover a position of absolute as well and position it.

```
body, html { height: 100%;
}

#cover { position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `div#cover` like this:

```css
#cover {
   background-color: red; 
   position: absolute; 
   border: 3px solid blue;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   top: 0; 
   left: 0; 
   bottom: 0; 
   right: 0; 
   display: none;
}  

@media print
{
    #cover { display: block; }
}
```

Your first page will be red with a blue border (or whatever it contains in the div)

The `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` make it fit to the viewport.

The `box-sizing` make it incorporate the border size at the div content width/height.

Without your HTML it's not possible to help further than this.